# Get a DocumentFile that is a child of a document tree without using findFiles()

Tags: java, android, storage-access-framework, documentfile

I have a tree URI that I got from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, **how can I get a DocumentFile that is a child of this tree without using `findFiles()`**? Given that I know how to get its documentId, its absolute path or its URI. I need the permissions associated with the document tree.

This is what I have right now:

```
DocumentFile rootTree = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, rootTreeUri);
DocumentFile docFile = rootTree.findFile(fileName);
```

It returns `docFile` as a TreeDocumentFile, child of my root. I have write permission and can use `createFile()` on it since it is under the document tree from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

So it works but `findFile()` is really slow.

If I try to use DocumentsContract like so:

```
// I know how to build the documentId from the file's absolute path
Uri uri = DocumentsContract.buildTreeDocumentUri(rootTreeUri.getAuthority(), documentId);
DocumentFile docFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri);
// Result: "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/1A0E-0E2E:myChildDirectory/document/1A0E-0E2E:myChildDirectory"
```

It returns a new TreeDocumentFile rooted at `docFile`, not `docFile` as a child of my original document tree (root). So I don't have write permission on this tree.

And if I try like so:

```
Uri docUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(rootTreeUri, documentId);
// Result: "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/1A0E-0E2E:/document/1A0E-0E2E:myChildDirectory"
```

I get a URI that actually looks like what I want, but it's a URI, not a DocumentFile.

If I do the same as above but build a DocumentFile from this uri with fromTreeUri():

```
Uri docUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(rootTreeUri, documentId);
DocumentFile docFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, docUri);
// Result: "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/1A0E-0E2E:/document/1A0E-0E2E:"
```

I get the original tree DocumentFile, not a DocumentFile representing the child.

Comment: "I get a URI that actually looks like what I want, but it's a URI, not a DocumentFile" -- use `fromSingleUri()` on `DocumentFile` to wrap that in a `DocumentFile`.

Comment: I don't have write permission on a `DocumentFile` created like that and can't use `createFile()`.

Comment: That's odd. AFAIK, you should have rights to the entire tree. Under the covers, `DocumentFile` just uses `DocumentsContract` for this sort of thing -- it's not like `DocumentFile` has special access that you don't.

Comment: @CommonsWare - the `SingleDocumentFile` created by `fromSingleUri` does not implement `createFile` (among other methods), even if created from a URI built with `buildDocumentUriUsingTree`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is not possible with the current APIs. The only way to get make a [TreeDocumentFile](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/core-utils/java/android/support/v4/provider/TreeDocumentFile.java) (the private subclass of `DocumentFile` that supports `createFile`, `createDirectory`, `listFiles`, and `renameTo`) is through `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri` (which only gives you the root tree URI as you've found) or through an existing `TreeDocumentFile`'s `listFiles()` method, which is what `findFile` uses internally.

You should file a feature request on [issuetracker.google.com](http://issuetracker.google.com) to add a new static method that does what you need.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm glad google fixed it and made accessing the external sd card better.

Comment: This should be addressed in androidx.documentfile:1.0.1 - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/documentfile#1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

There is possible solution:

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/orytnx/fixing_treedocumentfilefindfile_lousy_performance/

Below is citation from above link:

```
  @Nullable
static public DocumentFile findFile(@NonNull context, @NonNull DocumentFile documentFile, @NonNull String displayName) {


    if(!(documentFile instanceof TreeDocumentFile)) {
        return documentFile.findFile(displayName);
    }

    final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    final Uri childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(documentFile.getUri(),
            DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(documentFile.getUri()));

    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = resolver.query(childrenUri, new String[] {
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID,
                DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME,
        }, null, null, null);

        if(c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                if (displayName.equals(c.getString(1))) {
                    return new TreeDocumentFile(documentFile,
                            context,
                            DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(documentFile.getUri(), c.getString(0)));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "query failed: " + e);
    } finally {                 
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(c);
    }

    return null;
}
```

> Note that for accessing package protected class TreeDocumentFile, you will have to put function above in a helper class in package androidx.documentfile.provider. After this, replace all calls of DocumentFile#findFile by this replacement or a Kotlin adaptation of it.